# Linux user namespaces mapping issue - root without permission

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, root

I am trying to create a user namespace using `unshare`. Everything works fine when I map the parent user 'kevin' to the 'root' user in the new namespace:

```bash
kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $ ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 kevin kevin 4.0K Oct 14 17:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 kevin kevin 4.0K Oct 14 17:38 ..

kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $ unshare --user --map-root-user
root@raspberrypi:~/test # touch hello
root@raspberrypi:~/test # ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 14 17:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Oct 14 17:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 14 17:59 hello
root@raspberrypi:~/test #
```

When I try to map the root user in the parent namespace with the root user in the child namespace (using `sudo`), I do not have full permissions.

```bash
kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $ sudo unshare --user --map-root-user
root@raspberrypi:/home/kevin/test# ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4.0K Oct 14 17:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 nobody nogroup 4.0K Oct 14 17:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    0 Oct 14 17:59 hello

root@raspberrypi:/home/kevin/test# touch hi
touch: cannot touch 'hi': Permission denied
root@raspberrypi:/home/kevin/test#
```

I was expecting the touch command to succeed and for the resulting file to be owned by root in both user namespaces. I have checked the `/proc/self/uid_map` file and it seems like it is correct.

```bash
root@raspberrypi:/home/kevin/test# cat /proc/self/uid_map
         0          0          1
```

I also checked the capabilities of root in both namespaces using `getpcaps` and they are identical.

Note that I am able to create a new file if the current directory is owned by root.

What seems to be the problem?

Additionally, the following doesn't work either and I think it is related to this problem (originally I was trying to persist the user namespace):

```bash
kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $ touch user
kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $ sudo unshare --user=/home/kevin/test/user
unshare: mount /proc/1667/ns/user on /home/kevin/test/user failed: Operation not permitted
kevin@raspberrypi:~/test $
```